# How to remove all the line_item which do not have id field inside carrier_orders, there could be multiple carrier_orders

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I have a mongo doc, in which I need to remove all the line_items elements who's id is missing. The problem is carrier_orders itself an array, as well as line_items, is also an array.
below is the structure of the document:

```
{
    "carrierOrder": [
        {

            "id": 1636354,

            "costs": {
                "totalAmount": 110,
                "lineItem": [
                    {
                        "amount": 110,
                        "deleted": false,
                        "id": 3464888,
                        "price": 55,
                        "qty": 2,
                        "code": {
                            "id": 135431,
                            "key": "1600",
                            "value": "Freight - flat"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "deleted": true,
            "carrierPO": ""
        },
        {

            "id": 1668540,
            "costs": {
                "totalAmount": 110,
                "lineItem": [
                    {
                        "amount": 110,
                        "deleted": false,
                        "id": 3527307,
                        "price": 55,
                        "qty": 2,
                        "code": {
                            "id": 135431,
                            "key": "1600",
                            "value": "Freight - flat"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "amount": 110,
                        "deleted": false,
                        "price": 110,
                        "qty": 1,
                        "code": {
                            "id": 135431,
                            "key": "1600",
                            "value": "Freight - flat"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "deleted": false,
            "carrierPO": ""
        }
    ],
    "id": 3949038,
    "customId": "31428-26396"
}
```

I tried many queries and the closes I reach with below query

```
db.shipmentFormFieldData.update({"value.carrier_orders.$[].costs.line_items.$[].id":{$exists: false}},{$unset:{"value.carrier_orders.$[].costs.line_items":""}})
```

I want to remove all the line_items in which id field is missing

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.shipmentFormFieldData.updateMany({},
{
    $pull:{
        "carrierOrder.$[].costs.lineItem":{
            "id":null
        }
    }
})
```